# Update Multiple Records with help of Single Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am new to delayed_job. 
Here is my code which is executed on every update:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(VersionIncrementor.new(ids_array), 0 , 2.minute.from_now.getutc)
```

And the code within version_incrementor.rb is:

```
class VersionIncrementor < Struct.new(:ids_array)
  def perform
    ids_array.each{ |id| perform_update(id) }
  end
  def perform_update(id)
    #find record with id and update it
  end
end
```

Can we perform things like this ?

Please Help.

Comment: more than one person has that id?

Comment: No, id is uniq among all person objects.

Comment: ...except that it's returning an array, not a single object.

Comment: on this part: `Person.find(person_id).version + 1`

Comment: Can you give us the full stacktrace of the error (not just a "like" description of the error) ;) this should be about 30 lines of code listing the calling functions and the exact line number that raised the error. THEN paste in and identify the line-of-code referred-to by the error (to confirm it's the LOC we think it is)

Comment: @TarynEast: I had put the code.

Comment: @TarynEast: the error occurs in following line: Person.find(person_id).update_attribute("version", (Person.find(person_id).version + 1))

Comment: ok, so... when you are enqueueing, you are talking about `person_ids_array` ... but i your perform method it's talking about `person_array`. how do you get from one to the other?

Comment: secondly: as I said, you are fetching out person twice. try: `person = Person.find(person_id)`  then on the next line: `person.update_attribute("version", (person.version + 1))` just to see what happens. you might even want to try `raise "failed to find a person for #{person_id}!" unless person.present?` in between those two lines...

Comment: @TarynEast: ok. I did the changes, it gives same error. Can we execute more than 1 job using single delayed_job. (i.e. update attributes of more than 1 record within perform method) ?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood - this is code you would *like* to work. The short answer is "yes it's possible"... I'm not familiar enough with DelayedJob enqueuing to give you the right answer off the top of my head, but it has been done, it can be done... you just have to figure out the right way to pass an array of ids to delayed job, and you'll be fine.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be more help...